# What is the word that describes the quality of keeping multiple copies of something?

Tags: single-word-requests

It's an adjective I think. As in "The genetic code can be said to be (blank) because multiple codons can code for the same amino acid" or "My database is (blank) because it keeps multiple copies of critical files in case one is corrupted"

Hint: "backup" isn't the word I'm looking for.

Thanks folks.

Comment: Your two examples are of different things.   The genetic code is said to be *redundant* because different base sequences can code for the same amino acid.  In real-time computing, critical information like your database, is said to be *duplexed* (of course, that's only two) or *mirrored*.

Comment: THATS THE WORD!!! I was having such a hard time remembering the word redundant. Also, TIL on the database thing.

Comment: I understand that *redundant* is what you were looking for, but *fault-tolerant* also fits so I'll throw it out there.

Comment: I'm about to answer *redundant* but saw the comments... Why isn't it an answer?

Answer (score 2):

As posted in the comments by @deadrat;

[**Redundant**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/redundant)

Points 4 or 5 below

> redundant (rɪˈdʌndənt) adj
>
> 1. surplus to requirements; unnecessary or superfluous
> 2. verbose or tautological
> 3. (Industrial Relations & HR Terms) deprived of one's job because it is no longer necessary for efficient operation: he has been made
>    redundant.
> 4. (General Engineering) (of components, information, etc) duplicated or added as a precaution against failure, error, etc
> 5. (Electronics) (of components, information, etc) duplicated or added as a precaution against failure, error, etc

For you specific examples:

> The genetic code can be said to be *redundant* because multiple codons can code for the same amino acid
>
> My database is *redundant* [*has redundancy*] because it keeps multiple copies of critical files in case one is corrupted

NB: I'll delete this answer if @deadrat posts the same!